# Parsing a value from a JSON webpage

Tags: php, javascript, html

Using either javascript or php, how can I get a value from a webpage? This is the JSON I am attempting to parse:

> {"error":[""],"templateHtml":"",
>   "_visitor_conversationsUnread":"0","_visitor_alertsUnread":"0"}

I am trying to get the value of "_visitor_alertsUnread". 
How would I go about doing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either parse it using a regex, using json decoding, or simple indexing.  However, of these three, json is the most clean and correct way to go.

1) JSON decoding:

```
$page = file_get_contents($url);
$json_arr = json_decode($string,true);
return $json_arr['_visitor_alertsUnread'];
```

2) Regular expression:

```
$page = file_get_contents($url);
$pattern = ".*?_visitor_alertsUnread\\\":\\\"(\\d)\\\"";
preg_match($pattern, $page, $matches);
return $matches[1];
```

3) Indexing:

```
$page = file_get_contents($url);
$needle = "_visitor_alertsUnread";
$startpos = strrpos($page, $needle) + strlen($needle) + 3;
$endpos = strrpos($page, "\"", $startpos);
return substr($page, $startpos, $endpos);
```

Comment: Regarding 2nd aprach. Is iterating over the JSON object a good idea when you already know the key?

Comment: Good point; as far as cpu usage goes, I'd assume accessing via the key would be more efficient. Editing that now.

Comment: Yuck, **please** don't encourage an inexperienced user to parse what is apparently well-formed JSON with a regex!  Use the correct tool for the job, `json_decode()` really should be the first answer.

Comment: @therefromhere That doesn't warrant a downvote, as I am showing the user the various ways the issue can be solved. All programmers, especially inexperienced ones, should consider multiple possibilities as answers when faced with a problem.  Regardless, I do agree with you, and I have edited the answer to promote json decoding over the other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The response is in JSON.

If you just want to get the value of _visitor_alertsUnread then you can do something like this.

```
var JSONObj = {"error":["Security error occurred. Please press back, refresh the page, and try again."],"templateHtml":"\n\n\n\n\t</a>\n\t\n\t\tThe following error occurred:</h2>\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\tSecurity error occurred. Please press back, refresh the page, and try again.</label>\n\t\t\n\t\t</div>\n\t\n</div>","_visitor_conversationsUnread":"0","_visitor_alertsUnread":"0"};

alert(JSONObj._visitor_alertsUnread);
```